# ios - adding a Podcast feed to my app

Tags: ios, uitableview, xml-parsing, rss, podcast

In my app I want to list my feed and it's episodes in a UITableView so users can listen to it.
It is just one feed, so not replicating the Podcast app or anything.

To add a Feed (I am using jellycast.com) is it just like adding a regualr RSS Feed using an XML Parser or do I need to have something else to make that work.
I understand that I need implement a media player, but for now that is a later step.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Yeah, just a basic XML file to be parsed. Pretty easy stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a podcast feed should be RSS. I use this to parse RSS:

https://github.com/kballard/feedparser

Why write any code when someone has done it all for you? :)

The media player is also dead simple; iOS gives you the MPMoviePlayerController which does all the heavy lifting when you hand it a URL.

Comment: Yup was thinking about that to play the media - cool thanks for that:-)